# Gstreamer appsrc invalid buffer size error on feeding 1610x996 image

Tags: opencv, gstreamer, nvidia

I am trying to feed nvidia h264 encoder (nvvidconv) OpenCv Mat using the following pipeline :

```
#define CAPS_APPSRC "video/x-raw, format=(string)I420,width=(int)1610, height=(int)996, framerate=25/1"
#define CAPS_NVCONV "video/x-raw(memory:NVMM)"
#define CAPS_OMX "video/x-h264, stream-format=(string)byte-stream"
descr = g_strdup_printf ("appsrc name=src_name ! " CAPS_APPSRC " ! omxh264enc ! " CAPS_OMX " ! h264parse ! flvmux ! filesink location=test.mp4");
```

a Mat frame size of 1610x996 BGR converted to I420

```
cvtColor(g_frame,frame420,CV_BGR2YUV_I420);
```

g_frame is 1610x996

frame420 comes out as 1610x1494 [ (1610x1494*1.5) =2405340]

In appsrc callback after color conversion I allocate a new buffer and copy Mat data like this:

```
    size = frame420.step * frame420.rows;

    buffer = gst_buffer_new_allocate (NULL, size, NULL);
    gst_buffer_map(buffer,&info,GST_MAP_WRITE);

    memcpy(info.data,frame420.ptr(),size);
    gst_buffer_unmap(buffer,&info);
```

and then feed the buffer to appsrc like this:

```
GST_BUFFER_PTS (buffer) = timestamp;
    GST_BUFFER_DURATION (buffer) = gst_util_uint64_scale_int (1, GST_SECOND, 25);
    timestamp += GST_BUFFER_DURATION (buffer);
    g_signal_emit_by_name (appsrc, "push-buffer", buffer, &ret);
```

But when I run the pipeline, it gives the following error :

```
0:00:00.079123916  4112   0x2ac400 ERROR                default video-frame.c:149:gst_video_frame_map_id: invalid buffer size 2405340 < 2410320
0:00:00.079192404  4112   0x2ac400 ERROR            omxvideoenc /dvs/git/dirty/git-master_linux/external/gstreamer/gst-omx/omx/gstomxvideoenc.c:1778:gst_omx_video_enc_fill_buffer:<omxh264enc-omxh264enc0> Invalid input buffer size
```

Among the buffer sizes mentioned in the error "**2405340 & 2410320**" 2405340 is understandable because its my data size and is being fed as input. Where is 2410320 coming from ?

And why is this actually happening ?

Now if I just resize my buffer to 1600x996 the same pipeline works fine. It also works fine for any standard resolutions e-g 1280x720 etc

Comment: Since I420 is a 4:2:0 subsampling format - why is the buffer size not "width * height * 3 / 2"? Apart from that perhaps the encoder has some format restrictions on the input - like width and height dividable by 8/16/32? Stride/rowbyte values?

Comment: it is infact "width * height * 3/2" . and maybe you are right about input restrictions.

Comment: Hi, have you found the reason? Encountered similar error with omxvp8enc.